# How to place images on top of each other relative to a div element?

Tags: image, stack, z-index

I want to **stack images** on top of each other **relative to the div element** they are in.

All the answered questions I've seen only stack elements *on a blank page*. My images need to *remain in this div container tag*, so setting my position to absolute would not work here.

Example code to use (none of the images belong to me):
https://jsfiddle.net/Jonjei/3qymLn8v/4/

Any other general suggestions or tips are more than welcome as well.

HTML

```
<!-- images are placeholders and belong to their respective owners -->
<div class="container">

<img class="dog1" src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple5/v4/da/83/ae/da83ae00-d126-1200-1588-c74c59aa1a38/source/256x256bb.jpg" alt="">

<img class="dog2" src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/petmd-puppy-weight.jpg" alt="">

<img class="dog3" src="https://vetstreet-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com/56/d831705c9f11e19be6005056ad4734/file/puppy_training-tips-335mk022012-200454626-001.jpg" alt="">

</div>
```

CSS

```
.dog1 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: auto;
}

.dog2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dog3 {
  position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}

.container {
    background-color: #afbed8;
    border: 5px transparent solid;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin: 2% 10% 2% 10%;
    padding: 0px 7% 0px 7%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know your image sizes, you can give them negative `top` values;

```
.dog2 {
    position: relative;
    top: -260px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dog3 {
  position: relative;
    top: -619px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Or you can give your `.container` div a fixed height and set the dogs to `position: absolute;`